# how to find out count of occurrence particular element in each row of nd array?

Tags: numpy, count

```
[['fake' 'fake' 'fake' 'fake' 'fake']
 ['real' 'real' 'real' 'real' 'real']
 ['real' 'real' 'fake' 'fake' 'real']
 ...
 ['real' 'real' 'real' 'real' 'real']
 ['fake' 'fake' 'fake' 'fake' 'fake']
 ['fake' 'fake' 'fake' 'real' 'fake']]
```

here is my data set, I need to find out whether the fake or real prediction count is greater in each row of nd array and store the result in 3rd array, is there any function available in NumPy array for such operation kindly help regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data have dimensions `(n,2)`, you could do:

```
import numpy as np
# Example array
a = np.array([['fake', 'fake', 'fake', 'fake', 'fake'],
              ['real', 'real' ,'real' ,'real' ,'real'],
              ['real', 'real', 'fake', 'fake' ,'real']])

# For n even this will bias into the 'real' category
print(np.sum((a == 'fake'), axis = 1) > a.shape[1] // 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your array (*arr*) contains either *fake* or *real*,
you can run:

```
moreReal = (arr == 'real').sum(axis=1) > arr.shape[1] / 2
```

Details:

- `(arr == 'real')` - converts your array into a *bool* array (whether
  each element is *real*).
- `sum(axis=1)` - generates sums by each row.
- `... > arr.shape[1] / 2` - whether the number of *real* elements (in
  particular row) is greater than a half of row size.

The result is:

```
array([False,  True,  True,  True, False, False])
```

i.e. rows 1, 2, and 3 have more *real* entries than *fake*.

## Edit

If your starting point is a plain pythonic list of lists, start from
creation of a *Numpy* array:

```
arr = np.array([
    ['fake', 'fake', 'fake', 'fake', 'fake'],
    ...
])
```

Then, if you want to generate a **bool** array, run:

```
isReal = arr == 'real'
```

Comment: @ valdi_bo and@ lith but my labels are in real and fake, how to convert these boolean values in NumPy array to labels real and fake. where Fakse should be fake and True should be real.

Comment: I have already answered your question: *(arr == 'real') - converts your array into a bool array (whether each element is real)*.